# My function doesn't work on || tags

Tags: php, function

I've written a function to make menu roll down if the page is the same as I declare.

The function looks like this

```
 function menu_current()
 {
    $current = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if ($current === "index?p=config" || "index?p=maintenance")
        echo "class=\"nav-top-item suballowed current\" ";
    else
        echo "class=\"nav-top-item suballowed\" ";
 }
```

It works perfectly if I only declare 1 page

```
if ($current === "index?p=config")
```

but not more. How to solve that solution? And is there a way to `declare` all websites between `||` tags in one `variable` instead of writing them like I did?

Answer (score 4):

Replace this

```
if ($current === "index?p=config" || "index?p=maintenance")
```

with

```
 if ($current === "index?p=config" || $current ===  "index?p=maintenance")
```

otherwise PHP doesn't know what should be equal to `index?p=maintenance`

Comment: Thanks, is there another way of declaring that in just 1 variable? So that I can simply write `if ($current === $all_pages_in this_variable)`  ?

Comment: Probably not. The function that comes to my mind is `in_array()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Technically it's not a matter of "PHP doesn't know what should be equal to ...". Given [operator precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), you'd be evaluating `===` before `||`, thus (`$current === "index?p=config"` _OR_ `"index?p=maintenance"`). Since that non-empty string is "truthy", the result will always be _true_.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your approach if you set both sides of the equality check every time:

```
if ($current === "index?p=config" || $current === "index?p=maintenance") { ...
```

Perhaps a more "readable" solution:

```
if (in_array($current, array( 'index?p=config', 'index?p=maintenance' )) { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use a switch statement with a default.

```
function menu_current()
{
    $current = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    switch($current) {
        case "index?p=config":
        case "index?p=maintenance":
            echo "class=\"nav-top-item suballowed current\" ";
            break;
        default:
            echo "class=\"nav-top-item suballowed\" ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code

```
  function menu_current()
     {
        $current = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

        if ($current == "index?p=config" || $current == "index?p=maintenance")
            echo "class=\"nav-top-item suballowed current\" ";
        else
            echo "class=\"nav-top-item suballowed\" ";
     }
```